# How to center textViews inside linear layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout, android-xml

I have a table layout with 7 rows.

Every row I want to split into 4 parts uniformly and write some number in each section.
So I insert a linearLayout inside row and inside linear layout add 4 textViews.

The code of this tableRow is:

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="fill_horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@color/line_true"
            android:textSize="50dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@color/line_true"
            android:textSize="50dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@color/line_true"
            android:textSize="50dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@color/line_true"
            android:textSize="50dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</TableRow>
```

I have tried different variants of gravity, but all of them do not center numbers! And numbers look like they are closer to the left side.

It looks like this: (**just look at line with large numbers 1,2,3,4**)
[image]

How to set this problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
<TableRow
android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="fill"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:gravity="fill_horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:weightSum="4" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1"
android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="@color/line_true"
        android:textSize="50dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="@color/line_true"
        android:textSize="50dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="@color/line_true"
        android:textSize="50dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="0"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="@color/line_true"
        android:textSize="50dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Nice Example, You should tell the OP what you did to get it to work though :
android:weightSum="4" specifies that the components within the LinearLayout need their weights to add up to 4.

Setting each to android:layout_weight="1" gives each an equal spacing.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `android:gravity` to center on the TextView.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set all the width of your text view as 0dp, the attribute weightsum of the linear layout to be 4 (one per column). Tablerow with no gravity and no weight attributes.

Check that and tell what happens!

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code to achieve your layout:

```
<TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="50dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="50dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="50dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="50dp" 
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </TableRow>
```

Add `android:gravity="center"` and `android:layout_width="0dp"` to `TextView`.

I hope its work for you.